# How to force IIS7 to see changes in Web.config immediately?

Tags: web-config, iis-7.5

I don't have command line access (AFAIK). I'm using the IIS7.5 client (remotely)

I've tried resetting the Application Pool but the changes still don't show up (I have a Rewrite from http> httpS that may have a bug. So I deleted it from web.config and uploaded to root.)

So, either IIS7 takes a while to see it's changed, or the Rewrite is somewhere else, but where?

Comment: If you wrote a redirection rule (301 in most cases), then the cache is in your browser, not IIS. You need to clean browser cache, and then your new rule can start to take effect.